# Magento2: How to add custom message with shipping method?

Tags: magento2.3.1, customize, custom-shipping-method

I am using [this](https://www.magepsycho.com/magento-2-custom-shipping.html) extension for custom shipping method.

Now I want to show custom message with this shipping method So it will show in whole checkout process.

Can anyone please help me to achieve like this.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Custom message to be fixed for all?

Comment: Require custom message for store pickup only. and that is static for at the moment.